# Application server v/s HTTP server

Tags: web-services, web-applications, unicorn, haskell-warp

So I have noticed that the docs for various Application Servers (think Unicorn, Puma for Ruby, Warp for Haskell etc) always mentioned something similar to "it is optimized as an app server.” Typically this is mentioned when describing the standard setup of using a HTTP server (like Ngnix) in reverse-proxy in front of app servers.

So my question is: What exactly does the programming of a web application server make it more performant for serving data generated by code v/s HTTP server? Is there any particular engineering trade-offs? Or is it more the case where HTTP servers are optimized for serving files from a disk, and so they're merely trying to say that HTTP servers are not optimized for application code?

Comment: Oh, and links to specifics part of the source code for these application server implementations would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First, this really belongs in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

But basically, Apache & Nginx strictly deliver static web content. Yes, you can install PHP as a module & it will parse scripts when the page is requested. But it is all on demand. Meaning the program runs only when the page is requested.

In contrast application servers run programs that are active in memory all the time. Which can have some engineering benefits depending on what you want your system to do. So Tomcat or Passenger (for Ruby) run Java & Ruby apps, and are optimized to do it in a production server environment.

Why does Apache or Nginx get attached as a front end? Because at the end of the day Apache & Nginx still are the best tools for simply delivering web content.  And have better optimizations & security in place to do so.

So the application server focuses on making Java or Ruby run as cleanly as possible & deliver basic web content.  And Apache & Nginx concentrate on the front-end side of web delivery.

As a systems administrator, I prefer to proxy via Apache or Nginx since I already know how to configure & optimize those tools for my use. If I have to learn how to fine tune Passenger or Tomcat, it should only be enough to allow me to get it running so I can place Apache or Nginx in front of that.